# Java ArrayList<String> to single string without using loop

Tags: java, string, arraylist, string-concatenation

I have an `ArrayList<String>` that is added to periodically. What I want to do is to cast the entire ArrayList to a `String` without doing a loop. Can anybody tell me is it possible without using loop?

Edited:
So we found some solutions, Like

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Or

```
String result = String.join(",", list);
```

or some others as well. Now Just for getting knowledge I put a question which one is the most optimal way for compiler?

Comment: Why don't you want a loop?

Comment: Just trying to get best optimal solution

Comment: `arrayList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "))` is one of the options.

Comment: Any option, no matter how fancy it looks, will use a loop under the hood. Use a loop and go for the most straightforward and idiomatic implementation, that will be the best to do here.

Comment: "Best optimal solution" - You will not find a faster solution, all solutions somehow need to iterate through all items once. You can stream it for adding multi-threading to it. But the list needs to be huge for that to pay off.

Comment: You could always use Apache commons library, where it’s just ‘StringUtils.join(list, ", ")’

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a stream out of your list and collect it using joining collector :

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
```

You can pass the separator to `Collectors::joining` method for example :

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("-"));
```

Or you can use [String::join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) method :

```
String result = String.join(",", list);
```

where `,` is the separator.

Answer (score 2):

Given some `ArrayList<String> s`, all you need to use to get a `String` representation is `s.toString()`.

The format is the following

```
[element1, element2, element3]
```

Comment: To expand: what you get from ArrayList.toStirng is a comma-separated list of elements, enclosed in brackets.  (Of course, there probably is a loop involved, just not one that you have to write)

Answer (score 2):

I Believe you can do

```
String.join(", ", list);
```

Hope this helps :)